# Function to write any object as a pair to a file

Tags: c++, ofstream

I've tried to write a template function which should write pairs of objects (of different types) to a file. It's like this:

```
template<class A, class B>
void write_parameters(const std::string &file_name, std::initializer_list<std::pair<A, B>> parameters) {

    std::ofstream file;

    if (!file_exists(file_name)) {
        file.open(file_name, std::ios_base::app);
    } else {
        file.open(file_name);
    }

    if (!file) {
        throw std::runtime_error("file failed to be created");
    }

    for (std::pair<A, B> p : parameters) {
        file << std::string(p.first) << " = " << std::string(p.second) << "\n";
    }

    file << "---------------------------------------------\n";
    file.close();
}
```

The problem is, I just realized, that I need to pass the types for `A` and `B` when calling this function, so I can't call this function with multiple different maps, or can I?

Here's what I tried to call:

```
write_parameters<std::string, std::string>(std::string("parameters/") + s.instance_name, {
        {"starting_node", std::string(starting_node},
        {"max_iter",      max_iter},
        {"nice_gain",     nice_gain},
        {"lazy",          lazy},
        {"random_start",  random_start}
});
```

but this doesn't work, since, e.g., `max_iter` is not a string. How can I solve this problem without needing to call `write_parameters` for every map?

Comment: This sound more like a job for [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead of an `std::initializer_list` I think.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How can I iterate through a parameter pack argument? Or how would you write the contents to the file through the parameter pack?

Answer (score 1):

Pass and capture a pack of pairs which correspond to the parameters you want written. Then you use this cool trick to invoke a callable with each argument in the pack:

```c++
namespace detail{
template<class F,class...Ps>
void invoke( F&& f, Ps&&... ps ) {
    using pack=int[];
    (void)pack{((f(move(ps)),0))...};
}
}
```

Now this becomes:

```c++
template<class...Ps>
void write_parameters( std::string const& file_name, Ps&&... ps) {
  std::ofstream file(file_name,ios_base::app|ios_base::out);

  if (!file) {
    throw std::runtime_error("file failed to be created");
  }

  detail::invoke(
    [&](auto&& p) { file << p.first << " " << p.second << '\n'; },
    forward<Ps>(ps)...
  );
}

int main() {
  write_parameters(
    "parameters/" + s.instance_name,
    make_pair("starting_node", starting_node),
    make_pair("max_iter",      max_iter),
    make_pair("nice_gain",     nice_gai),
    make_pair("lazy",          lazy),
    make_pair("random_start",  random_start)
  );
}
```